# function which takes address() and gives value

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I want to make a cell equal to the cell above it.

When I write

```
=address(row()-1;column())
```

It just writes the name of the cell above(for example for B2 it writes $B$1)

Is there a function which inputs the address and puts the value?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try using the [**OFFSET**](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/offset-function-HP010342739.aspx) function to offset the cell by -1 row.
For example you can paste the below formula into cell A2 and it will return the value of A1:

```
=OFFSET(A2,-1,0)
```

If, however, you really want to keep your present address method, put it inside of the [**INDIRECT**](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/indirect-function-HP010062413.aspx) function like this:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()))
```

Comment: Be aware if you use INDIRECT it is volatile and will cause excessive calculation

Comment: Agree with Jesse, there's almost never any reason to use INDIRECT unless you've got yourself into a pickle. In this case offset is also pointless as instead of =OFFSET(A2,-1,0) as a formula you should just use =A1